# Single entry Schengen visa type C (Del-Lon-Sweden (via Lon)-Paris-Lon-Del)

Tags: visas, schengen

I am travelling to London from Delhi in next 8 hours (and then to Schengen countries) and I need some quick help in confirming my understanding of the visa type-C single entry Etats Schengen.

And I have a valid UK multiple entry visa also.

I am flying by British Airways as below with itinerary spread across next some days.

Delhi - London
London - Gothenburg
Gothenburg - Paris (but the flight will go back to London and then proceed to Paris)
Paris - London
London - Delhi

Now I understand that I can enter the Schengen area only once through any Schengen country and once I exit Schengen area through any country, I can't re-enter with same visa.

This being the case, will my travel from Gothenburg to Paris (via connecting flight through London) be called as exiting the Schengen area since I will be going to Paris via London?

Essentially, will there be a round of immigration pass through when I will travel from Gothenburg to Paris via London?

Comment: Unfortunately, your travel via London will in fact count as leaving the Schengen area.  You will pass through Schengen exit controls when you leave Gothenburg, and through entry controls when you arrive in Paris.  You will probably not pass through immigration controls in London.  If I were you, I would rebook that flight for one that does not touch down outside the Schengen area.

Answer (score 5):

As phoog noted, your flight to London will count as exiting the Schengen area. Leaving Gothenburg you will pass immigration exit control, and once again entry control in Paris.

Your options in this case seem limited to rebooking your flight to Paris as not to pass through the UK (or any non-Schengen country for that matter)

Comment: There are even nonstop GOT-CDG flights available.